# Disable Carriage return

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I am using simple UDP connection.

I would like to know if by default the connection has  "Carriage return" enabled or disabled, and how could I set that property?

thanks,

ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eh, that's not entirely accurate. UDP isn't differentiated by virtue of sending text vs. binary. All network protocols ultimately send data as bit streams (binary). What typically differentiates it is that unlike TCP, there is no back and forth to establish sequence numbers for tracking packets, and no ACK flag to signal that a packet was received. UDP will send packets with no regard to whether or not they get to the destination.

Edit: Ray maybe you should provide a little more detail about what you're trying to do. Carriage Return is an ascii character just like any other. It has a numerical representation and occupies a byte of space just like the other ascii characters. So asking if it's "enabled" for UDP transmission isn't really a valid question. Any series of bits can be sent via UDP, or TCP, or any other protocol - which means UDP doesn't even understand what ASCII is, or the letter "b", or a carriage return. It's all just a bunch of 1's and 0's, and UDP is aware of IP addresses and Port numbers - just enough to send your bits of data somewhere. What your application does with those bits is the question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I guess i didn't really understood what CR means. I thought it's some property which you set on the object. same as you can enable/disable it with regular windows TELNET program.

Comment: Well, you can prevent a Carriage Return from being used for something, but that's an application level thing that you would have to code, and doesn't have anything to do with UDP. If you elaborate, maybe someone can help, but I think your issue is specifically Java and not network related.

Answer (score 1):

UDP traffic is session/connection less. So you can't have a "connection" on UDP.

UDP is used to pass binary data rather than text and there is no way to disable carriage return or any other character.

Comment: "no way to disable carriage return" so you say it's enabled in anyway?

Comment: It not something you enable or disable.  A UDP packet has no special handling for any particular byte value, carriage return or any other byte value.

Answer (score 0):

`UDP` broadcasts binary data - if you encode `\r` and/or `\n` to bytes and add it to the message, it will be sent. No filtering, no conversion on this protocol layer.